# Vagrant + multiple providers for different work environments

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, qemu, vagrantfile, libvirt

Hello Vagrant experts out there!

I ran into a bit of a problem.

I'm trying to setup a `vagrantfile` with `centos` environment using `virtualbox` as a provider and it seems to work great.

So whats the problem?
One of our developers is working behind `qemu` on linux.
When trying to run the current `vagrantfile` with `virtualbox` it collides with `libvirt`, they refuse to work together.

Is there a way to write a single `Vagrantfile` for different work environments?
Meaning when I run the file on a machine with `virtualbox` installed it will run with a `virtualbox` provider and when running on a different machine with `qemu` it will run with `qemu` as a provider?

If not - is there a smarter way to do it?
I guess I'm not the only one out there the encountered the issue..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using 3rd party provider (like `vagrant-libvirt`).

[Vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/basic_usage.html#VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER) is mentioning that you can select default provider in couple of ways:

1. Set `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` env variable.
2. Use `vagrant up --provider`
3. Set multiple `config.vm.provider` options. The first available will be used.